# MySQL: Duplicate entry for key (Formerly "What does 'idx' mean?")

Tags: mysql

Update: After a lot of painful research, I've discovered what the problem actually is and updated the title to make a little more sense.  I'll put my answer below.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to copy the query that's giving me this problem because it belongs to my company, so I'll have to keep my question very specific.

I have an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` query that's returning this error:

```
Duplicate entry <gobbledygook> for key 'idx_<tablename>'
```

The tablename at the end is the correct name, but it has this weird `idx_` prefix before it that's not a part of any of the tables I'm currently working with.  What is that `idx`?  Does it have something to do with the `information_schema`?

Update:  Apparently, I need to clarify something:  There is no column with `idx` in the name.

Comment: It's index and probably needs to be unique.

Comment: It's a unique index that's being violated.

Comment: Look at the table's definition.

Comment: that's just the human-readable name of the key, an abstraction layer so you don't need to know/see what the real internal identifier of the key is. it can literally be anything: ``alter table foo add index `himom` (dad, sis)`` - boom, one key named "himom".

Answer (score 1):

The numerous websearches didn't reveal much when I was trying to solve this problem, but I did finally figure it out (and JohnH's answer helped me to do this).

I finally discovered that "idx" is not something created by MySQL, but a name that someone else gave to the index.  I have never come across a uniqueness constraint on an index that wasn't a key before, so I didn't know where that error came from.

This command showed all of the indices:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM <tablename>
```

And I was able to see that non-unique was set to 0 for this key.

To fix the problem, I was able to simply drop the index and recreate it, without adding a uniqueness constraint.

```
DROP INDEX idx_<tablename> ON <tablename>;
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ADD INDEX idx_<tablename> (<comma-separated columns>);
```

Whether or not removing the uniqueness constraint is a good idea remains to be seen, but it's also beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

"idx_" is a common prefix for index names.

You many have an index that does not allow duplicate values for the column values referenced by that index.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the unique index had duplicate entries even though the column being indexed didn't. I can only think this was caused by a bug. Solution was

- Stop the service that writes to the db
- Drop the index
- Recreate the index
- (Do the operation that was previously failing)
- Start the service

It's important if you are dropping an recreating an index that nothing can be given an opportunity to insert a duplicate entry while you are doing this. This is why I stopped the service that writes to the db.